# html selector option selected based on django provided variable value

Tags: django, html, drop-down-menu

I have a django app that returns a list of table rows into a html table and one of the fields is supposed to be an selector with a set of predefined values and selected value has to be the one provided as a variable from django app. Here's the code:

```
<table>
    <thead>stuff here</thead>
        <tbody style="font-size: 10px">
        {% for ticket in scope %}
        <tr>
            <td id="tId" name="tId">{{ ticket.0 }}<input type="checkbox" id="accept" name="accept" value="{{ ticket.0 }}"/> <br />Select</td>
            <td hidden><input name="list_{{ ticket.0 }}" value="list_{{ ticket.0 }}"/></td>
            <td>
                <select id="lvl4" name="lvl4">
                    <option id="ticket1" value="{{ ticket.1 }}">{{ ticket.1 }}</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>{{ ticket.2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ ticket.3 }}</td>
            <td>{{ ticket.4 }}</td>
            <td>{{ ticket.5 }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Set of available values:

- value1
- value2
- value3
- value4 "wrong ticket type"

Set of values retrieved from the SQL table:

- value1
- value2
- value3
- value4 (select the "wrong ticket type" option)
- value5 (select the "wrong ticket type" option)

What I want to achieve with this select field is to select `{{ ticket.1 }}` matching option or the `"wrong ticket type"` if there is no matching option.

Please let me know if more information is needed.
Thank you for your support.

**EDIT:**
Code of the select tag I would like to achieve:

```
<select id="lvl4" name="lvl4">
<option value="value1">value 1</option>
<option value="value2">value 2</option>
<option value="value3">value 3</option>
<option value="value4">wrong ticket type</option>
</select>
```

With option value selected that equals the `{{ ticket.1 }}` value or `"value4"` if no match.

Comment: `{{ ticket.1|default:"wrong ticket type" }}` ?

Comment: @AnnaVracheva, could you explain your code a little bit? I'm not very experienced in Django and don't know how it solves my problem.

Comment: I not sure that totally understand your problem. But if you need to display `{{ ticket.1 }}` and if it's not exists or null, display some default text, you can use template tag `default`.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. You want the output in a table or a select widget in a form? For the second, use a django form (probably with some logic in the __init__ method for deciding on matching options).  And what do you mean by a "matching option" what has to match what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments suggested my question is not clear which I agree it could be the case. Please forgive me, English is not my native language, but I'm trying :)

In the meanwhile a colleague of mine provided me with a solution I was looking for.

And here it is:

```
<select name="lvl4_{{ ticket.0 }}">
<option {% if ticket.1 == "Run Support" or ticket.1 == "User Support" %}selected {% endif %} disabled>incorrect ticket type</option>
<option {% if ticket.1 == "Change Request" %}selected {% endif %} value="Change Request">Change Request</option>
<option {% if ticket.1 == "Internal Ticket" %}selected {% endif %} value="Internal Ticket">Internal Ticket</option>
<option {% if ticket.1 == "Enhancement Request" %}selected {% endif %} value="Enhancement Request">Enhancement Request</option>
<option {% if ticket.1 == "Technical Request" %}selected {% endif %} value="Technical Request">Technical Request</option>
</select>
```